# Render table values dynamically using Ajax after page load in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dynamic-tables

My idea is to get connectivity status of available servers in database on a php page.

```
  <tbody>
  <?php foreach ($data['servers'] as $server) { ?>
     <tr>
          <td class=""><?php echo $server->server_name; ?></td>
          <td class=""><?php echo $server->base_path; ?></td>
          <td class="server_status"><?php if (is_dir($server->base_path)){ echo 'Pass';} else { echo 'Fail' } ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php  } ?>
  </tbody>
```

I want to do this just after page load using ajax like this [page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNCCT.png)

How do I call ajax to get each value of this dynamically generated table. So far, I have tried the following code

```
<?php foreach ($data['servers'] as $server) { ?>
     <tr>
          <td class=""><?php echo $server->server_name; ?></td>
          <td class=""><?php echo $server->base_path; ?></td>
          <td class="server_status"></td>
          <td class="server_status_loading"></td>
    </tr>
  <?php  } ?>
```

JS

```
$(function(){

$(".server_status").hide();
$(".server_status_loading").show();
$.ajax({
    url: 'get-server-status'
})
.error(function(){
    alert('Error!');
})
.done(function(response){

    $(".server_status_loading").hide();
    $(".server_status").show();
    $(".server_status").html(response);
});
```

get-server-status function:

```
    public function getStatus() {

    $basep = $this->_serverModel->getBasePath(2);
    if (is_dir($basep)) { 
        echo 'Pass'; exit;
    } 
    else { 
        echo 'Fail'; exit;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to provide a means of identifying which server you're testing the status of in PHP. Presumably that would be either the server name or its base path. You can use the `data` attribute of `$.ajax` to send this information to your PHP script.

Comment: you shud pass each element's database id in ajax, then you can add the response.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - How do i send serverID to data attribute in this case?

Comment: We cannot use same class name to render the response. How to handle response? @NiranjanNRaju

Comment: give id to tr, let the id be database

Comment: Is there any other way to do this? Plz help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first add `id` to your `<tr>`.

```
<?php foreach ($data['servers'] as $server) { ?>
 <tr id="echo database id here.">
      <td class=""><?php echo $server->server_name; ?></td>
      <td class=""><?php echo $server->base_path; ?></td>
      <td class="server_status"></td>
      <td class="server_status_loading"></td>
</tr>
```

then check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kYZYU/4/) link to handle the ajax on page load and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kYZYU/5/) link to handle the ajax on click.Rest everything is provided there.

In link you can replace `status` to `server_status_loading`

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var hTable = document.getElementById('table2');
        var iRowCount = hTable.rows.length;

    for(var i=1; i<iRowCount; i++){
        basepath= hTable.rows[i].cells[2].childNodes[1].value;      
        $.ajax({
           url: 'get-server-status',
           data :basepath 
        })
    .error(function(){
        alert('Error!');
    })
    .done(function(response){
        hTable.rows[i].cells[2].childNodes[3].value=response;
    });

    }
}
```

Comment: you are dealing with `ajax` which are async in nature. You don't know which response will come first. So `for` loop will not work. Please rethink on it.

Comment: then  you have to retrive status with your $server  variable or async : false in ajax call